# OFFSET error with symfony project and MS SQL backend

Tags: sql-server, symfony1

I am building a symfony 1.4 project with an MS SQL backend. I built a backend using the admin generator but when I attempt to load an admin module I am getting this error:

```
OFFSET cannot be used in MS SQL without ORDER BY due to emulation reasons
```

How do I resolve this?

The symfony application is running on Debian squeeze under Apache 2.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case the error disappeared by setting the pager size explicit:

```
list:
    max_per_page: 20
```

Edit: That wasn't the solution, I just had some sorting paramters in the session which solved the problem temporarily.

The new solution is to define a defalut sorting. I did it by overriding the index action:

```
class organisationActions extends autoOrganisationActions
{
  public function executeIndex(sfWebRequest $request)
  {
    // sorting
    if ($request->getParameter('sort', 'created_at') && $this->isValidSortColumn($request->getParameter('sort', 'created_at')))
    {
      $this->setSort(array($request->getParameter('sort', 'created_at'), $request->getParameter('sort_type')));
    }

    // pager
    if ($request->getParameter('page'))
    {
      $this->setPage($request->getParameter('page'));
    }

    $this->pager = $this->getPager();
    $this->sort = $this->getSort();
  }
}
```

> $request->getParameter('sort'**, 'created_at'**)

instead of

> $request->getParameter('sort')

Answer (score 1):

Based on my glance at the Doctrine API, it is SUPPOSED to support this feature, but may be broken for some versions of MS SQL.  Unfortunately I don't have MS SQL any longer to experiment.

If you can get along without doing paging at all, a workaround could be to disable it by setting

```
  list:
    max_per_page: false
```

in your generator.yml file for the modules using admin.

Comment: Unfortunately there is enough data that we need paging.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this (or a similar) problem. I was getting that error message, and I narrowed it down to a problem with the paging in Symfony. If I took out the paging stuff from the component action, I could get past it.

The answer turned out to be very simple: just order the main query (i.e. the query that the pager gets applied to). In my case, it was adding this:

```
->orderBy('i.created_at DESC')
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Okay, technically this problem resides in MS SQL, but IMO an abstraction layer should take care of this.

Answer (score 1):

Just an FYI. The backend admin generator pagination get's stuck on certain pages using OFFSET n; at the end of a doctrine query. The solution is to clear the SESSION COOKIES.

I kept getting blank pages in the backend. I analyzed my mysql queries and saw OFFSET 60 was being added to every query. This happened after I had deleted all records from the database table.